# Get specific items from bs4.element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have element with type bs4.element.Tag:

```
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 35id</span></div>
```

And I need to get "1003 : 11400" from this element. Please, how to do that?

Thank you

EDIT:

and how can I select individual elements ("1003 : 11400", ...) if I have more than one divs:

```
    <div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 35id</span></div>,
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 36id</span></div>,
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1007 : 11550

    <span class="table_v_time" title="13. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 37id</span></div>,
```

...

Comment: Have you tried your_element.text ?

Comment: get the element via `xpath`. Then just do `element.text` , it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_ = "table_v_nr")
print(div.find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 35id</span></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "table_v_nr")
print(div.find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
1003 : 11400
```

**Edit:**

If you wanted to extract the text from multiple `div` tags, then you can try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 35id</span></div>,
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

    <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 36id</span></div>,
<div class="table_v_nr">
    1007 : 11550

    <span class="table_v_time" title="13. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 37id</span></div>,
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

[print(div.find_next(text=True).strip()) for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = "table_v_nr")]
```

Output:

```
1003 : 11400
1003 : 11400
1007 : 11550
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="table_v_nr">
    1003 : 11400

   <span class="table_v_time" title="12. min. 2. hr. 6. day.">Y 35id</span></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "table_v_nr").contents[0]
print(div.strip())
```

Output:

```
1003 : 11400
```

**Edit** you can use a CSS Selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select (".table_v_nr:contains('1003')"):
    print(tag.next.strip())
```

Output:

```
1003 : 11400
1003 : 11400
```

Comment: can I select it separately. I need: 1, add all this numbers (1000 : 10000,...) into matrix (pandas dataframe)

Comment: 2, or select only ones that interest (first, third,...)